# I need a Script that brings up a Gui on touch in Roblox?

Tags: roblox

How do I make a script bring up a shop GUI when a brick is touched?

And how should I make the "buy" stuff in the shop GUI?

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you.  Perhaps if you narrowed the question down to a specific area that you're having trouble with, someone would be able to point out a solution.

Answer (score 7):

**You will be needing to make that Shop Interface yourself**,
but i will give you the "GUI Giver" script.
Note: You must put the Script **Inside** the Brick/Part.

```
local GUI = game:GetService("ServerStorage"):WaitForChild("GUI") -- Recommended to place your GUI inside of ServerStorage

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local Player = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if Player then
        if not Player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui"):FindFirstChild(GUI.Name) then
            GUI:Clone().Parent = Player.PlayerGui
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a script that connects a brick's 'Touched' event to a function which uses the "getPlayerFromCharacter" method of game.Players to find the player then inserts the GUI into the player's "PlayerGui". For example:

```
function newGUI()
    --enter something that makes a shop GUI then at the end returns the 'ScreenGui' it's in.
end

script.Parent.Touched:connect(function(hit)
    local player = game.Players:getPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent);
    if player ~= nil then
        newGUI().Parent = player.PlayerGui;
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be used to give the player the shop gui:

```
local ShopGui = game.Lighting.ShopGui -- This should be the location of your gui
local ShopPart = workspace.ShopPart -- This should be the shop part

ShopPart.Touched:connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent == nil then return end
    if hit.Name ~= "Torso" then return end
    local Player = game.Players:playerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if Player == nil then return end
    if _G[Player] == nil then _G[Player] = {} end
    if _G[Player].ShopGui == nil then
        _G[Player].ShopGui = ShopGui:Clone()
        _G[Player].ShopGui.Parent = Player.PlayerGui
    end
end)

ShopPart.TouchEnded:connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent == nil then return end
    local Player = game.Players:playerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if Player == nil then return end
    if _G[Player] == nil then return end
    if _G[Player].ShopGui ~= nil then
        _G[Player].ShopGui:Destroy()
        _G[Player].ShopGui = nil
    end
end)
```

Note that "ShopPart" should be a big part that cover the whole shop area (preferable invisible)

Then you also have to build a shop gui.

In the shop gui you should make TextButtons (or image buttons) that each contains the following script:

```
local Cost = 100
local ThingToBuy = game.Lighting.Weapon -- Make sure this is right
script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
    local Player = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent -- Make sure this is correct
    if Player.leaderstats["money"].Value >= Cost then -- Change "money" to anything you want (it     must be in the leaderstats tho)
        Player.leaderstats["money"].Value = Player.leaderstats["money"].Value - Cost
        ThingToBuy:Clone().Parent = Player.Backpack
        -- GuiToBuy:Clone().Parent = Player.PlayerGui
    end
end)
```

The code ain't tested, so it might contain errors. And you might need to change more stuff than mentioned. But it should give you an idea on how to make the shop gui =)